# Python regex error: Cannot get the correct result with re.match function

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Now I have 2 data that I want to check if the email address in one table matches with the regex pattern in another table.
My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def matched_data(input):
    s = 'yyy'
    for values in blockdf['Pattern']:
        if re.match(re.escape(r'{}'.format(values)), input):
            return True
    return False


emaildata = [['xxx@abc.com', '2020-07-01'], ['yyy@abc.com', '2020-07-20'], ['zzz@bcd.com', '2020-07-31']]
blockdata = [['*@abc.com', '2020-07-01'], ['aaa@*', '2020-07-20'], ['zzz@bcd.com', '2020-07-31']]

emaildf = pd.DataFrame(emaildata, columns = ['Email', 'Date'])
blockdf = pd.DataFrame(blockdata, columns = ['Pattern', 'Date'])

emaildf['Match'] = emaildf['Email'].apply(matched_data)
print(emaildf)
```

The result was:

```
         Email        Date  Match
0  xxx@abc.com  2020-07-01  False
1  yyy@abc.com  2020-07-20  False
2  zzz@bcd.com  2020-07-31   True
```

The problems that I got were:

1, I tried to return True when there is a match with regex pattern and email address.
And when I use the following command to avoid the issue of * in regex:

```
print(re.match(re.escape('*@abc.com'), 'xxx@abc.com'))
```

It returns none.

2, At the same time, the table in reality consists of millions rows of data, which means it is not pratical to use a for loop to loop through all record. In this case, how shd I optimize the script?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: It looks as if `*` is a wildcard. In regex, it is `.*`. Instead of `re.escape('*@abc.com')`, you need `re.escape('*@abc.com').replace(r'\*', '.*')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew or just have `'.*@abc.com'` in the "pattern dataframe" to begin with,  then it can be used directly.

Comment: @DeepSpace Well, `r'.*@abc\.com'` would be ideal.